# How can I add a custom message for @Column(nullable = false)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I was previously using @NotNull to validate the fields of a class as follows: `@NotNull(message = "Vendor ID must be fetched from Orders")`. However, I decided to replace the `@NotNull` validation with database-level constraints, using `@Column(nullable = false)`. Is there any way to add the custom message to this validation, similar to the one present with the `@NotNull` version of the validation, such that I get the specified message in case of violation of the constraint?

Comment: No, you can not. In case when the constraint will be invalidate you will get db specific error message.

Comment: @SternK In that case, could I use both `@NotNull` as well as `@Column(nullable = false)` over the same field? Or would this be overkill?

Comment: Yes, you can. Note that `nullable = false` has a sence only if you use hibernate [schema generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation).

Comment: @SternK Yes, I happen to be using schema generation. If you like, you can put this in an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `@Column(nullable = false)` and `@NotNull` are completely independent things.

1. The `@Column(nullable = false)` make sense only if you use hibernate [schema generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation). And violation of this constraint will lead to the db level error with db specific error message.
2. The `@NotNull` is a part of [bean validation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank). And violation of this constraint will lead to the application level error that can be customized.

Answer (score 1):

Since `@Column` describes a db property, it cannot do a validation at the level you want: if you say `@Column(nullable = false)`, you are not saying the setter parameter cannot be null, you are saying that that column cannot be null, so you will have a validation and a message at the database level.